# jenkins: performance plugin shows only recent build data in the perf report

Tags: jenkins, jmeter, performance-testing

I set up jmeter job in jenkins, which supposed to publish *.jtl results and then display them in a nice trend graph.
But, depite that I see that they're published under the builds//performance-results/JMeter folders, the trend always shows only current day results. So if I run this build three times during a day - I'll see graph with a three points. If it was just one run today - I'll see 1 run on that graph. I don't see yesterday and etc results on graph. I'd like to see this trend to display all the data from all the previous builds, including yesteday, etc.
What should I check, how perf plugin decides which *.jtl data to use to display data??

in settings of the job I have this regexp for jtl source: ****/*.jtl, so I would expect all the builds data being displayed on the trend ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently the solution is very simple. Found it myself!
By default all jtl files had a timestamp at the beginning, thanks to jmeter-maven-plugin. Pattern was yyyyMMdd. Trend report in jenkins displayed last build results. And because of the pattern jtl results for all builds run this day were the same, and were different for previous day. 
So, easiest solution was to remove that timestamp from the results file name.

```
<testResultsTimestamp>false</testResultsTimestamp>
```

in configuration part of jmeter-maven-plugin in the pom file.

Annoying, is that Performance plugin guys haven't put it into the documentation, - the requirement for results file to have the same name in order to be displayed on the graph...

Comment: The most important point is performance plugin expects file name to be same and should not have any dynamic values like ddmmyyy etc. I was facing the same issue and now after removing the timestamp from jtl filename this issue is resolved. Thanks a lot @javagirl for this helpful question and answer

Answer (score 0):

Apart from that, there is an issue with Performance plugin (version 1.12 and 1.13). Due to that, the LastReport (image doesn't show) and other reports are showing missing info.

To fix it, either you can download/git clone the latest code from Performance Plugin github repo and build it locally (using mvn clean install and you'll get performance.hpi Jenkins plugin file) OR revert back to Performance plugin 1.11 version.

As 1.12/1.13 have some other enhancements over 1.11, I selected to build myself, until someone will fix Performance Plugin and come up with a recent release version (aka 1.14 containing the fix for this issue).

Issue: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-27100